# Jess pattern matching 'not' condition on rule

Tags: jess

I'm playing on jess. I want to make rule that is not using '~'.

Here is my code.

```
(clear)
(reset)

(deftemplate person
    (slot name)
    (slot eyes)
    (slot hair))

(defrule person-without-brown-hair
    (person (name ?name) (hair ?hair&:(not brown)))
=>
    (printout t ?name " does not have brown hair." crlf))

(assert (person (name "Jeon") (eyes green) (hair brown)))
(assert (person (name "Park") (eyes blue) (hair red)))

(run)
```

What I expected was variable ?hair is not brown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the function `(not ...)` negates its argument. TRUE is true, FALSE is false, and any other symbol is true.

To test whether a slot value is equal or not equal to some value, use `(eq ...)` or `(neq ...)`  or `(= ...)` or `(<> ...)`.

```
(defrule person-without-brown-hair
    (person (name ?name) (hair ?hair&:(neq ?hair brown)))
=>
    (printout t ?name " does not have brown hair." crlf))
```

Result:

```
Park does not have brown hair.
1
```

Direct matching is, of course, preferable.